# What is the best solution of motion interpolation by CPU?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, interpolation, media, video-processing

I've been using FFmpeg's "minterpolate" filter to implement motion interpolation to get a higher frame rate for a while. However, because "minterpolate" doesn't support hardware acceleration and multithread, it is very slow to finish that process, particularly on devices that only have CPU, which make the situation worse because I cannot use neural network such as [DAIN](https://github.com/baowenbo/DAIN)(by SJTU).

Thus, I would like to ask for some alternatives for "minterpolate" filter, which is supposed to be faster and has a decent quality.

I knew SVP can do, but it is not open-sourced and therefore it cannot be integrated to other software.

Comment: Try this hack on minterpolate: https://gist.github.com/majal/1e63a511b41faeae188083777f8e4b46